# Recognised Graduate visa (subclass 476) and iBT for Australia?

Tags: visas, australia

This is a statement from [this](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/476.aspx) page:

> ..., you must achieve a score of at least 6 in each of the four
>   components of the International English Language Testing System
>   (IELTS) **or another language test** and score specified by the Minister
>   for Immigration and Border Protection.

What does it means with "or anther language test"? Is TOEFL acceptable as well?

Comment: Although I actually wonder if this should be on expats.stackexchange.com instead...

Comment: Questions about immigration or moving for extended periods of time (studies or employment, among others) are off-topic. Our sister site, [Expatriates Stack Exchange](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask. See also the meta post [Is it OK to ask questions about immigration?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1281/793).

Comment: @mindcorrosive It all about a visa. That visa could be used for short travle.